# Make a repository of an entire partition?

Tags: git, version-control, configuration, debian

I like to have a good backup from my small debian server.

Would it be a good idea to make a repository at "/"?

Comment: Also.  Version Control != Backup.  Have a look at something rsync based.  Duplicity perhaps.  Then set it up to backup to Amazon S3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.  There are a lot of continually changing files under directories like /var/log that are not suited to using a version control tool.  Also, files under /dev and /proc are not regular files and can't really be versioned in the way a VC tool would expect them too.

Backup software is a much better fit for what you're after, probably something like: tarsnap; backula or a similar package.

Answer (score 1):

Git isn't a back up tool, no version control system is a substitute for a backup tool. The don't conceptually serve the same purpose, and don't functionally either. Not to mention that there are directories that constantly change and symlinks and other file-like things that aren't really files that a version control tool wouldn't even begin to understand what to do with them.

If you want to **version** your entire partition so that you can edit config files and such willy nilly and revert changes, you could do that with a very extensive and complex `.gitignore` file, accomplish that. But even that would be done better by creating localized repositories in just the locations that have the files like `etc` for example.